# Empty project groups after Netbeans update

Tags: netbeans, installation, project

I recently upgraded from Netbeans 7.3.1 to 7.4 and all my project groups contain no projects in the newer version. I have not moved my projects at all and I chose to import all my settings from the previous Netbeans installation when prompted.

Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind my mistake, I downloaded the Netbeans + JDK from the Oracle website and forgot it doesn't come with PHP support. Please close this question.